# Javascript modify existing array with object of different key

Tags: javascript

I've got this snippet of code

```js
const name = 'test1'
const payload = [
    {
        "manSegChildId": "5497",
        "manSegChildDesc": "test4"
    },
    {
        "manSegChildId": "5314",
        "manSegChildDesc": "test1"
    },
    {

        "manSegChildId": "5159",
        "manSegChildDesc": "test5"
    }
]

const newObj = payload.map(nameObj => {
  if(nameObj.manSegChildDesc === name) {
    return {
    "id": nameObj.manSegChildId,
    "label" : nameObj.manSegChildDesc,
    "disabled": true
    }
  }
});

console.log(newObj)
```

I need simply an object I'm returning and not an array and not this undefined ones. Also, is there any optimal way so perform this changes

Expected O/P

```
{
   "id": 5314,
   "label" : "test1",
   "disabled": true
 }
```

Comment: and what is your expected output?

Comment: Are you try to filter the object in array based on `manSegChildDesc1` and next perform map?

Comment: is there only 1 test1. if so first find it using array.find then use its properties to create the object

Comment: `const match = payload.find(x => x.manSegChildDesc===name); const newObj = {id: match.manSegChildId, label: name ,disabled: true}`

Comment: The `.map()` method expects the callback function to *always* return a value. If it does not, the result array element will be `undefined`.  What you might want is to use `.filter()` first and then `.map()` afterwards (if there might be more than one match).

Answer (score 1):

```js
const name = 'test1'
const payload = [
    {
        "manSegChildId": "5497",
        "manSegChildDesc": "test4"
    },
    {
        "manSegChildId": "5314",
        "manSegChildDesc": "test1"
    },
    {

        "manSegChildId": "5159",
        "manSegChildDesc": "test5"
    }
]
// Variant 1: in case you have multiple matches
const newObjMultipleMatches = payload.filter(nameObj => nameObj.manSegChildDesc == name)
                      .map(x => ({ disabled: true, ...x }));
// select first match or work with all matches (change if required)                      
console.log(newObjMultipleMatches[0]);                      
// Variant 2: only at max. a single match 
const newObjSearchResult = payload.find(nameObj => nameObj.manSegChildDesc == name);
if(newObjSearchResult !== undefined){
  console.log({ disabled: true, ...newObjSearchResult });
}
```

[`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) always projects every element in the input set to an element in the target set (here I mean set in a mathematical sense), therefore the number of elements in the input set and the output set is always identical.

If you wanna trim down the number of elements you need to [`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) or if you want to trim it down to a single element, you need to [`find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) this single element.
If none of the items matches the condition for `find()` or `filter()` you either get an empty array for `filter()` or `undefined` for `find()`.

The rest is a matter of [desctructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/operators/destructuring_assignment) or creating a new object (when you want to change the property names).